# DirectPayment method Paypal problem

Tags: c#, paypal

I am trying to implement Direct payment method as I have user's credit card information etc in my database. This is the sample that I am referring:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using com.paypal.sdk.services;
using com.paypal.sdk.profiles;
using com.paypal.sdk.util;
using com.paypal.soap.api;

namespace ASPDotNetSamples
{
    public class DoDirectPayment
    {
        public DoDirectPayment()
        {
        }
        public string DoDirectPaymentCode(string paymentAction, string amount, string creditCardType, string creditCardNumber, string expdate_month, string cvv2Number, string firstName, string lastName, string address1, string city, string state, string zip, string countryCode, string currencyCode)
        {

            com.paypal.soap.api.DoDirectPaymentReq req = new com.paypal.soap.api.DoDirectPaymentReq();


            NVPCallerServices caller = new NVPCallerServices();
            IAPIProfile profile = ProfileFactory.createSignatureAPIProfile();
            /*
             WARNING: Do not embed plaintext credentials in your application code.
             Doing so is insecure and against best practices.
             Your API credentials must be handled securely. Please consider
             encrypting them for use in any production environment, and ensure
             that only authorized individuals may view or modify them.
             */

            // Set up your API credentials, PayPal end point, API operation and version.
            profile.APIUsername = "sdk-three_api1.sdk.com";
            profile.APIPassword = "QFZCWN5HZM8VBG7Q";
            profile.APISignature = "AVGidzoSQiGWu.lGj3z15HLczXaaAcK6imHawrjefqgclVwBe8imgCHZ";
            profile.Environment = "sandbox";
            caller.APIProfile = profile;

            NVPCodec encoder = new NVPCodec();
            encoder["VERSION"] = "51.0";
            encoder["METHOD"] = "DoDirectPayment";

            // Add request-specific fields to the request.
            encoder["PAYMENTACTION"] = paymentAction;
            encoder["AMT"] = amount;
            encoder["CREDITCARDTYPE"] = creditCardType;
            encoder["ACCT"] = creditCardNumber;
            encoder["EXPDATE"] = expdate_month;
            encoder["CVV2"] = cvv2Number;
            encoder["FIRSTNAME"] = firstName;
            encoder["LASTNAME"] = lastName;
            encoder["STREET"] = address1;
            encoder["CITY"] = city;
            encoder["STATE"] = state;
            encoder["ZIP"] = zip;
            encoder["COUNTRYCODE"] = countryCode;
            encoder["CURRENCYCODE"] = currencyCode;

            // Execute the API operation and obtain the response.
            string pStrrequestforNvp = encoder.Encode();
            string pStresponsenvp = caller.Call(pStrrequestforNvp);

            NVPCodec decoder = new NVPCodec();
            decoder.Decode(pStresponsenvp);
            return decoder["ACK"];

        }
    }
}
```

This is the link:

https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/nvp_DoDirectPayment_cs.txt

However, I am getting error 'NVPCallerServices' cannot be found. I already have reference to paypal_base. Can anybody tell me what is the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, thats the Pay Pal API :)

The sample is likely a bit outdated. The `NVPCallerServices` class seems to be named `CallerServices` now.

So try to replace the line

```
NVPCallerServices caller = new NVPCallerServices();
```

with

```
CallerServices caller = new CallerServices();
```

Comment: I didn't expect that to happen because I am referring the latest doc - the one on their site. Paypal is aweful. Don't know why clients prefer that.

Comment: It feels like pay pal has countless versions of sdks api documentation sites and payment products spread all over the web... its really disgusting :)

Comment: Paypal doc's suck - I have no idea how I would of figured this out with out this answer.